# wrong file name, but it's correct

Tags: php, pdf, download, file-exists

I'm trying to create download buttons so that users can download pdf-files on the click of a button. I have this:

```
<?php

session_start(); // Alltid överst på sidan

if(!isset($_SESSION['sess_id']) OR $_SESSION['sess_id'] < 1){
   die("Skapa ett konto som investerare för att enkelt få tillgång till affärsplaner!");
}else if(is_numeric($_SESSION['sess_id'])) {

    /* kolla om användaren försöker ange filer i en annan mapp */
    if(substr_count($_GET['file'], "/") > 0){
        die("Invalid path"); }


/* skapa fullständig sökväg till filen */
$file = '/server/php/files/' . $_GET['file'];

/* kolla om filen finns */
if(!file_exists($file))
{
   die("Invalid filename");
}
```

and it's giving me a "Invalidfile name" message..

however, 
When I `echo $file;` and copy the path to my browser(+localhost in front) it serves me the download dialogue that I'm looking for. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

output of `echo $file`

```
/server/php/files/roibay-business-plan.pdf
```

and "`server`" is a folder in my root folder.

Comment: Just an FYI that using $_GET like that without filtering it can lead to security issues. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: I have some filthering code :)  (I'll add it so that it's there), but thank you!

Comment: Can you please post the output to the `echo $file` command?

Comment: Are you using symlinks in the server structure anywhere? `file_exists` and symlinks do not work so well together.

Comment: Can you just for fun try this?  `file_exists($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/php/files/roibay-business-plan.pdf"))` Assuming that `/server` is your root.

Comment: So I'll try file_exists($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/server/php/files/roibay-business-plan.pdf"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've set up localhost with mamp and I've created an alias which is
>   lab.local and so the filepath I'm talking about is:
>   lab.local/server/php/files/somefile.pdf and when I enter that into the
>   webbrowser the dialogue pops up but file_exists does not validate that
>   path

That means that the `server` directory is not your root. Try this:

`file_exists($_SERVER{'DOCUMENT_ROOT'} . "/server/php/files/roibay-business-plan.pdf"))`

Comment: I thought that the folder above server might have been the server root :)

Comment: It's weird though. You said the `server` dir is in your `root` dir. Does that mean that your root directory is your websites root folder?

Comment: I't what I thought I'm probably mistaken

Answer (score 2):

> When I echo $file; and copy the path to my browser it serves me the download dialogue that I'm looking for.

That's because `file_exists` expects a path name relative to the server; not a URI.

- [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Example:

```
file_exists('/var/www/site.com/index.htm'); // this would work.
file_exists('www.site.com/index.htm'); // this would not
```

Comment: but the path is relative: /server/php/files/somefile.pdf

Comment: What is /server/php? It depends what your PHP root is. If I were to try to include `/index.htm` on my server config, it would not look for index.htm in `/var/www/mysite.com`. But if I tried to include `index.htm` (no preceding slash), it would look in a different spot.

Comment: @Alisso You keep saying relative. Do you mean your path in your file system is: `/server/php/files/bla.pdf` or `/var/www/html/server/php/files/blad.pdf`?

Comment: I've set up localhost with mamp and I've created an alias which is lab.local and so the filepath I'm talking about is: lab.local/server/php/files/somefile.pdf and when I enter that into the webbrowser the dialogue pops up but file_exists  does not validate that path